# Como atualizar BD sqlite java android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Como eu faço para adicionar uma coluna no banco de dados da minha aplicação android java sem perder os dados do banco de dados atual?
O meu código:

```java
public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_DESCRICAO + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

E quando eu adiciono uma coluna ela não é criada, pois a tabela já existe e mantém as colunas atuais.

Comment: Acho que ficaria mais fácil de responder se você incluísse o que fez até o momento, um trecho do código atual ou pelo menos o que você já tentou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte DDL:

`ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN nova_coluna CHAR(50)`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253804/insert-new-column-into-table-in-sqlite

Adicione este código no método `onCreate()`, logo após o seu  `CREATE TABLE`. Além disso, adicione à sua query de criação a condição de criar somente se não existir, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TALBE IF NOT EXISTS table ...restante da query
```

Assim, quando uma nova versão do banco (ou a primeira instalação do app) for instalada a tabela será criada somente se não existir, preservando os dados já instalados (quando o app for atualizado), e o `ALTER TABLE` irá mudar a estrutura da sua tabela.

Esses comandos apenas serão executados na primeira vez que o nova versão do banco for instalada (ou a primeira instalação do app).

Testei aqui e deu certo.

Comment: Boa! essa linha tem que ser rodada somente uma vez? se rodar de novo vai dar conflito?

Comment: Coloque essa linha no `onUpgrade()` e altere a versão do banco de dados, ela será chamada quando a versão do banco de dados for alterada. @EmersonBarcellos

Answer (score 0):

Grande o que você também pode fazer, se for o caso, é criar uma classe com informações estáticas sobre o alter table que vai atualizar sua base com controle de versão:

abaixo etá o método do upgrade:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String vers[] = null;

    /* AQUI É ONDE OCORRE A MÁGICA PARA ATUALIZAÇÃO DO BANCO, AO ESCREVER O CÓDIGO
     * DO BANCO VI QUE AO ATUALIZAR A VERSÃO DO BANCO, DE ACRODO COM
     * TODOS AS ORIENTAÇÕES, FAZ O DROP DA TABELA ATUALIZADA E DEPOIS RECRIAVA ELA, 
     * FIZ A ALTERAÇÃO PARA QUE AO MODIFICAR A VERSÃO DO BANCO, 
     * O DESENVOLVEDOR POSSA PASSAR OS DADOS CONTIDOS NA CLASSE ATUALIZACOESBANCO E
     * COM ESSES DADOS POSSA REALIZAR A ATUALIZAÇÃO */

    try {

        /* ELE PEGA A ÚLTIMA VERSÃO DO BANCO E COMPARA COM A NOVA, DE ACORDO COM A 
         * COMPARAÇÃO ELE VAI NA CLASSE ATUALIZACOESBANCO E COLETA OS SCRIPTS
         * DAS VERSÕES QUE ESTÃO PENDENTES E EXECUTA UM A UM */

        for (int i = oldVersion + 1; i <= newVersion; i++) {
            vers = new AtualizacoesBanco().selectScript(i);

            /*você pode utilizar qualquer table defitions para realizar 
              esse procedimento*/

            updateTabelasBanco(db, vers[0], vers[1],
                    vers[2], vers[3]);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

abaixo temos o modelo da classe de controle de versão:

```
public class AtualizacoesBanco {

// o modelo de atualização que é para ser passado no metodo onUpdate do        tabledefinition
// das tabelas na classe SthBancoOpenHelper é esse abaixo
// TABELA , CAMPO , TIPO , VALOR DEFAULT

public static String VER_1[] =  {"CONFIGURACAO", "NAO_VENDER_TITULO_ATRAZO", "TEXT", "S"};


/*AO CRIAR O CAMPO COM A VERSÃO ACIMA, VOCÊ DEVERÁ INFORMAR LOGO ABAIXO NO MÉTODO
SELECTSTRING O CASE DA VERSÃO, NO CASO DO MÉTODO ELE SEMPRE IRÁ RETORNAR INICIANDO DA 
VERSÃO 1 POR CONTA DE QUE A PRIMEIRA VERSÃO PUBLICA COM AS ALTERAÇÕES
*/
public static String[] selectScript(int ver){
    switch (ver) {
    case 1:
        return VER_1;
    default:
        return null;         
    }

}

}
```

o método abaixo pode ser inserido na classe openHelp que você criou:

```
//com esse método você vai pode alterar a estrutura das tabelas de seu banco
public static void updateTabelasBanco(SQLiteDatabase db, String table,
        String column, String typ, String valor) {
    try {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + table + " ADD " + column + " " + typ);
        if (valor != ""){
            db.execSQL("update "+ table +" set "+ column +" = '"+ valor +"'");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

com isso você tem um controle de versão de seu banco, caso você esteja construindo um sistema onde o controle de versões deve ser bem rigoroso essa é uma ótima forma de manter o banco sobre controle;